# Multiple goodness of fit tests for multinomial proportions of unbalanced classes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, unbalanced-classes, multinomial-distribution

I am considering a case where I have a nominal variable with $L$ levels (let us say $L=2$ for simplicity) and a bunch of continuous features. I would like to test if the most centrally located point of each level in the space spanned by the continuous features is surrounded by observations possessing levels which are randomly scattered. What this means is that I am essentially testing whether the $k$-Nearest Neighbours of the most centrally located point for each level can be modeled as a Multinomial random variable with $k$ trials and probability vector $(p_1, \ldots, p_L)$ where $p_i$ is set to be equal to the proportion of observations possessing level $i$. I consider $k$ to be equal to $\alpha \times n_i$, with $n_i$ being the amount of observations of class $i$ and $0< \alpha < 1$.

My question is the following; suppose that it turns out that the $k$-Nearest Neighbours for the most centrally located points of classes 1 and 2 are all of the same respective class (i.e. all nearest neighbours of class 1 are of the same class and similarly for class 2). My test statistic values would then be given by $\alpha \times n_2$ and $\alpha \times n_1$ for the same test applied on 2 (potentially) different subsets of the data. If the 2 levels are highly imbalanced and $n_2$ is much greater than $n_1$, I would end up with a much larger $p$-value for the 2nd test. I do not only care to reject my null hypothesis here but I would also like to "interpret" these $p$-values in a way and potentially do inference based on them but the different sample sizes do not help. I am aware of the different corrections out there (Benjamini-Hochberg, Holm-Bonferroni, Šidák etc.) but I am unsure whether these would be suitable here, as I am also unsure whether I can make the assumption of the tests being independent. What would you recommend? Should I just drop the $\alpha$ parameter and set $k$ equal to the same value universally (i.e. for all $L$ tests)?